# Angular 2-Way Binding

Tags: angularjs

I have been having this issue with Controllers in Angular. I looked it up as much as possible, but I could not resolve the issue.

I am trying to implement a simple controller, but for the life of me, I cannot get the binding to work. It's not displaying my data. For example when I say, `{{ test }}`, I get just that, not the "Hello World!" string.

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Hi', function($scope){
 $scope.hello = "hello!";
});

app.controller('todoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.test = "Hello World!";
 $scope.formData = "";
 
 $http.get('/api/todos')
  .success(function(data) {
   $scope.todos = data;
   console.log(data);
  })
  .error(function(data) {
   console.log('Error: ' + data);
  });
 
 $scope.createTodo = function() {
  $http.post('/api/todos', $scope.formData)
   .success(function(data) {
    $scope.formData.text = "";
    $scope.todos = data;
    console.log(data);
  })
   .error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
  });
 };
 
 $scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
  $http.delete('/api/todos/' + id)
   .success(function(data) {
    $scope.todos = data;
    console.log(data);
  })
   .error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
  });
 };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
 <head>
  <title>TodoX</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- TodoX CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="todoCtrl">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
     <h1>TodoX<span>{{todos.length}}</span>{{test}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="list-group">
      <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy:date">
       <label class="list-group-item">
        <input type="checkbox"/> {{todo.text}}
       </label>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <form class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formData"/>
      <input type="submit" ng-click="createTodo()" placeholder="Submit" class="form-control"/>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Angular JS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- TodoX Core JS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" href="core.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: It's not displaying my data. For example when I say, {{ test }}, I get just that, not the Hello World! string.

Comment: And, it is correctly linked in the appropriate file path for Angular. I have even tried the CDN.

Comment: I think you have some errors in yours console. If your page displayed non binded data (only {{... }}) that's means an error occured with angular.
Check your console, and check if you have some errors

Comment: That was the first thing I did. & mysteriously, there are no errors in the console. =(

Comment: Strange... Need more informations. Can you provide a plunker with copy/past of your code.
Replace $http by a mock service that send promise

Comment: Thats just it, I have commented that controller & created a new one to see if I can get some sort of data to the view, but nothing has worked. I will try to set up a plunkr when I get a minute.

Comment: Your controller must be like this : https://plnkr.co/edit/SSJmydkSDyPjLjAR65v4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just executed your code while placing angular file link above the script tag, so that AngularJs is loaded before your script can call angular modules.

I think you're putting angular after your script which is why you are running into this issue. Your code works just fine. I tested it.

Put it like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Here `script.js` will be your controller script.

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/_pirateX/hovencdk/)

Comment: Wow, I just figured out my mistake. I was using HREF instead of SRC to link Javascript files. Such a silly mistake. Thanks guys!